# How to enable a drag and drop functinality in SharePoint 2013 form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a simple Intake form that I am building in SharePoint 2013. I want to add a capability/functionality that allows me to drag and drop emails to auto fill fields in the Forms. How can I accomplish that? or can that be done in SharePoint 2013?

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you program JavaScript?

Comment: Not expert in it. But definitely can build on top of the existing code or customize it to fit my need if I have an example available to me.

Comment: Then Client Side Rendering (CSR) is one way to go, you essentially enhance an existing Form with new functionality. I haven't seen specific examples here on SO